# We seem to be getting an unusual number of low quality posts

Tags: discussion, spam

It seems that today we are getting an unusually high number of low quality posts, link only answers, etc.

It could be the moon is in the 7th house and jupiter aligns with mars. Or it could be one of those pre-spam scenarios. I will let the mods decide.

Just a heads up! Be on the alert.

Cheers!!

Comment: Do me a favor and link to examples so we can gauge their quality as a group

Comment: @JohnConde I went to http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/users/36029/closetnoc?tab=activity and see only a couple of reviews. Is there a better way? This post was based upon what seemed to be an unusual number of reviews that were just one or two lines, link only, short terrible answers, etc. It just seemed like an unnatural burst of suspect activity. Sometimes you do not realize these things until you are down the road a bit and then you regret not paying better attention. Cheers!!

Answer (score 1):

Yeah, I noticed that too. Well, I do flag them. Some flags are declined, some are helpful. But last one was declined, so I don't know what to flag anymore except for spam.

[How to prove that a particular website is mine?](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/q/99166/56095)

This one is too broad for me. I marked it as a too broad question, flag was declined. Just wondering why.

Comment: I tend not to mark any question after the fact if there is a good answer and/or if a moderator has looked at it (commented or edited). It depends. Sometimes I do. It can be a tough call sometimes. I have found posts from years ago that should be deleted. And I have commented to mods that I can answer a question marked as broad quickly and easily. It can all be subjective sometimes. Cheers mate!!

Comment: True. That's why we're flagging that.