# Is this too broad question or not?

Tags: discussion

[Change Adsense account linked to DoubleClick for Publishers](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/q/99251/56095)

So... I don't know anymore. To adress this question by closenotc [We seem to be getting an unusual number of low quality posts](https://webmasters.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1463/56095), I agree that there is a many low quality posts.

I'm writing this here because I'd like to know what to do with this type of question. Is it ok or is it too broad for our community? Because, I don't want to answer on this question because it's too broad for me.

I'd like to discuss this a little bit, thanks

Comment: How is it broad?   Broad means that an answer for it wouldn't fit in the format of the site.    If the answer would require more than five paragraphs, it is too broad.  If there are entire books written to answer the question, it is too broad.   Too broad can also be somebody asking a laundry list of questions where each question would be better asked alone.

Comment: So, I can answer him just "YES." and that's it?

Comment: "YES" is not a high quality answer.  A high quality answer says "why" and gives evidence or references.

Comment: This is question for Web Applications SE in my opinion.

Comment: But this is question like... "can I type a web adress without www?"

Comment: For the sake of discussion. Let's say I ask this question because there's no question like that here. Would it be concidered too broad?

Comment: Web applications could be a fit, but they typically migrate questions about tools for webmasters here.   We have lots of questions about AdSense and DFP.   Those questions fit perfectly fine here.

Comment: Even for a question like  "can I type a web adress without www?", "YES" is a poor quality answer.   It would be good to explain how redirects work.   It would be good to explain that many browsers add the "www" for you.  It would be good to explain that there are some cases in which omitting the "www" might not work.

Comment: Ok. Thank you again for clarification Stephen. I just didn't know what to do with this type of questions, so it's better to ask here what's with that.

Answer (score 1):

If there are no questions like it here, it is potentially "off-topic" as opposed to "too broad". Contrarily, having many like questions is evidence that it is "on-topic". If there are old questions that would now be considered off-topic, moderators can lock them for historical significance to indicate they should no longer be used as evidence that like questions belong.

As for the specific question you point out, it certainly needs some edits. The grammar is poor. However, it does not appear to me to be either too broad, or off-topic.